# Headless Behavior Space with table extension

Tags: netlogo

I currently have a project that I've completed using the netlogo interface.

My project includes multiple .nls files and one of my .nls files use the table extension. I've created a behavior space experiment and named it experiment for simplicity.

I'm trying to run the experiment headless using the following commands in my Netlogo application's directory where the Netlogo.jar is located.

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp ./Netlogo.jar org.nlogo.headless.Main --model /path/to/file/experiment.nlogo --experiment experiment  --table /path/to/output/table-output.csv --spreadsheet /path/to/output/spreadsheet-output.csv
```

I'm getting the following error. It seems that I can't detect my extension from the .nls file. How can this be fixed?

```
Exception in thread "main" Nothing named TABLE:PUT has been defined at position 895 in 
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerExceptionThrowers$.exception(CompilerExceptionThrowers.scala:26)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser.org$nlogo$compiler$IdentifierParser$$getAgentVariableReporter(IdentifierParser.scala:107)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser$$anonfun$processToken2$2.apply(IdentifierParser.scala:75)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser$$anonfun$processToken2$2.apply(IdentifierParser.scala:68)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser.processToken2(IdentifierParser.scala:68)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser.processToken$1(IdentifierParser.scala:31)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser$$anonfun$process$1.apply(IdentifierParser.scala:34)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.IdentifierParser$$anonfun$process$1.apply(IdentifierParser.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.next(Iterator.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.toStream(Iterator.scala:1181)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.toStream(Iterator.scala:399)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anonfun$toStream$1.apply(Iterator.scala:1181)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anonfun$toStream$1.apply(Iterator.scala:1181)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1060)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1052)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Stream.scala:952)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Stream.scala:952)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator$LazyCell.v(Stream.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator.hasNext(Stream.scala:946)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:329)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator.isEmpty(Stream.scala:933)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StreamIterator.next(Stream.scala:948)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:898)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.head(Iterator.scala:885)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.recurse$1(ExpressionParser.scala:474)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.delayBlock(ExpressionParser.scala:479)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parseExpressionInternal(ExpressionParser.scala:339)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.org$nlogo$compiler$ExpressionParser$$parseArgExpression(ExpressionParser.scala:290)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser$$anonfun$parseArguments$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ExpressionParser.scala:96)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:81)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parseArguments(ExpressionParser.scala:95)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parseStatement(ExpressionParser.scala:80)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.ExpressionParser.parse(ExpressionParser.scala:55)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(CompilerMain.scala:34)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(CompilerMain.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:573)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.JavaConversions$JCollectionWrapper.foreach(JavaConversions.scala:592)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:29)
    at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:28)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromMap(HeadlessModelOpener.scala:53)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openString(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:531)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:513)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.newWorkspace$1(Main.scala:19)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
    at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$1.apply(Lab.scala:33)
    at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$1.apply(Lab.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.map(Range.scala:46)
    at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.run(Lab.scala:33)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:24)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:197)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the .nlogo file must contain the extension declaration rather than the .nls file.