# Headless BehaviorSpace cannot load extensions

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I am trying to run an experiment with BehaviorSpace from command line, but BehaviorSpace is not loading extensions. There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366890/headless-behavior-space-with-table-extension), bur I can neither understand the answer nor comment, so I will explain my issue here.

I modify the fire.nlogo model, add a random experiment called "experiment1" through the GUI and copy-paste from [guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0-BETA1/docs/):

```
java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp ~/Desktop/netlogo-6.0-M6-64/app/NetLogo.jar\
org.nlogo.headless.Main \
--model "~/Desktop/netlogo-6.0-M6-64/app/models/Sample Models/Earth Science/Fire.nlogo" Fire.nlogo" \
--experiment experiment1 \
--table -
```

This works.

Then I add

```
"extensions[csv]"
```

as first line in the model and run exact same command. This is what I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" Can't find extension: csv at position 11 in 
at org.nlogo.core.ErrorSource.signalError(ErrorSource.scala:11)
at org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.importExtension(ExtensionManager.scala:171)
at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1.apply(StructureParser.scala:70)
at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1.apply(StructureParser.scala:69)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parsingWithExtensions(StructureParser.scala:69)
at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parseSources(StructureParser.scala:35)
at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain$class.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:28)
at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:16)
at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:28)
at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:54)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromModel(HeadlessModelOpener.scala:68)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openModel(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:544)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openFromSource(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:540)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openString(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:526)
at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:508)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.org$nlogo$headless$Main$$newWorkspace$1(Main.scala:19)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$runExperiment$1.apply(Main.scala:24)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$2.apply(Lab.scala:33)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab$$anonfun$2.apply(Lab.scala:33)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.run(Lab.scala:33)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:24)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

If I repeat the procedure with Netlogo 5.3.1-64, I obtain a different error starting with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find extension: csv/csv.jar
```

I tried the bitmap extension instead of CSV, but no luck. Noticeably, the experiment works if I start it from GUI.

I use 
Ubuntu 16.10 and
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

For me it was resolved when I copied the folder `extensions` from `NetLogo/app/` into the `NetLogo` folder (right where the `netlogo-headless.sh` is usually located).